# Educational book on science of climate change with action items?

Tags: discussion

Can anyone recommend a book or books, intended for a non-scientific audience, which covers some (or all) of these elements?

- Basic science of global warming
- Evidence from ice cores, temp readings, etc
- Climate modeling and simulations
- Projected scenarios and impacts
- Actions that individuals can take to reduce impact, ranging from simple (eat less meat, adjust thermostat) to more demanding (switch to bike commute, buy electric car)
- Corporate actions (policy setting for organizations and companies, what to ask political candidates about, etc)

I am looking for something that emphasizes clarity, an engaging writing style, and a positive attitude about the possibility of averting crisis. After reading this book someone should feel that they have a good general understanding of what causes global warming, and know specific actions they can take which will have a measurable impact.

The intended audience for this book would be people who know climate change is a big deal, and know they should do something about it, but don't feel personally invested in the problem or solutions.

Comment: Perhaps the people at [Earth Science SE](http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com) can help you with this?

Comment: You may just have identified a gap in the market ...